# Why does my PHP site alternate between two cookie values?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

**Edit:** I was able to solve this on my own eventually. (See below.)

I'm currently building an online shop where you have many options to configure your product before buying. All configuration data is stored in the PHP session on the server. Although we have a separate button for starting a new configuration, it turns out that when helping clients many of our employees just open a new tab in Chrome and start their new configuration from there. If they go ahead and try saving their configuration data, all configurations in the single tabs get mixed up because they're all saved to the same data array in `$_SESSION`.

After some research on the internet (including SO) we decided on application IDs which are set at every execution of the script like `$app_id = time();`. The IDs are then included in the page and set as a JavaScript property within the script that is handling the configuration on the client-side. On every AJAX request the ID is sent along with the other data so that changes can be applied to the correct configuration.

Now the configuration data doesn't get mixed up anymore, but every time a user reloads the page, a new ID is set and the standard configuration is loaded. Google and SO one again pointed me in the direction of using cookies to solve my problem, like in this post: http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php So now I've added `onunload="prepareForRefresh()"` to my `<body>` tag, and I save the ID on every unload to a cookie called `APP_ID`. Then I've altered my PHP script to check for the existence of this cookie, like this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['APP_ID'])) { // ID has been set on unload

    $app_id = $_COOKIE['APP_ID']; // set ID to previous value
    $cookie = setcookie('APP_ID', '', time() - 4800); // unset cookie
    echo 'refresh';

} else {

    $app_id = time(); // set ID to new value
    echo 'new page';
}
```

It all works up to some point, the JavaScript correctly sets the cookie on unloading the page and my PHP script can access the stored value. Unfortunately, I think I must have missed something. My site now switches between two configurations on every refresh. Unsetting the cookie via JavaScript like `<body onload="deleteCookie"...` didn't work either. It almost seems to me as if at some point a wrong ID is written to the cookie and then it alternates between these two values.

How can I prevent that? Or would it help to set a `max-age` of 15 seconds for the cookie, so that it just kind of expires when the page is not reloaded?

**EDIT:** After some more digging around I think that my problem is most likely related to the request-response structure between client and server illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6648794/2956155). So I guess unsetting the cookie in either the `onload` or the PHP script won't change anything. But how do I have the ID remembered on page reload?

---

**Solution** (or at least what worked for me):

I've changed the part where I'm setting the ID in my PHP to:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['APP_ID']) && $_COOKIE['APP_ID'] != '') { // ID has been set on beforeunload

    $app_id = $_COOKIE['APP_ID']; // set ID to previous value

} else {

    $app_id = uniqid(); // set ID to new value
}
```

Then, in my JavaScript, I wrote two functions:

```
function unsetCookie() {

    document.cookie = 'APP_ID=;'; // unset cookie
}

function setCookie() {

    document.cookie = 'APP_ID=' + $('#my-element').data('app-id') + ';';
}
```

and registered these in the HTML: `<body onbeforeunload="setCookie();" onload="unsetCookie();">`

This might be a mighty dirty workaround, but it works. Comments, hints and tips are highly appreciated, I'm eager to learn and to improve. :)

Comment: Using `$app_id = time()` is not a good idea – if I open multiple new tabs at once, those requests might as well reach your server within the same second, and I end up with two identical “ids” again. Use `uniqid` instead.

Comment: And a cookie with a 15 second lifespan is not a good idea either – the client’s time might easily be “off” by such a value, and since it’s the client’s time that the cookie’s expiration date is compared against, that might resulting in the cookie expiring earlier than you want. And since you are using the same cookie name, I don’t even see how that should be able to solve your problem with multiple tabs – they would just overwrite the cookie value, and you’d be back where you started …

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for the hint about `uniqid()`, I will change that in my code.

Comment: About the overwriting: That are my thoughts exactly, depending on the client's time oder connection speed isn't a good idea. Seeing as the user can only be active in one tab at a time, I just want some indicator as to what is the active tab. And (in case of reload) I want to keep the ID and prevent my script from creating a new one via `$app_id = uniqid()`. Do you have any ideas?